# spliting string by comma mysql

Tags: mysql

Am write a string separate using msql, it works perfect for three strings e.g "eat,go,take"
but when i only use two it repeats the second string on the third one.

how do i set it to show only an empty string if there is only less than three strings

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 1) AS pri,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS sec,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS ter
FROM team WHERE playerId= 98538;
```

so if the third string is empty its repeating the second string on the third results 
how do i set it that if the last string is empty it only shows an empty string.

Here is the snip of what it shows if the i only have two strings separeted

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format of your emails in the `string` column is along these lines:

```
threeEmails1@gmail.com,threeEmails2@gmail.com,threeEmails3@gmail.com
```

I'd be inclined to use a sub-query for this, and then check whether the columns match the prior results when outputting the results:

```
SELECT  pri,
        CASE
          WHEN sec = pri THEN NULL
          ELSE sec
        END AS sec,
        CASE
          WHEN ter = pri THEN NULL
          WHEN ter = sec THEN NULL
          ELSE ter
        END AS ter
  FROM  (
        SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 1) AS pri,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS sec,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS ter
          FROM  team 
          WHERE playerId = 98538
        ) a
```

Here's a working example of it with three rows having 3, 2, and 1 email addresses to show the varying outcomes:

```
CREATE TABLE team (playerID INT, string VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO team VALUES (98538, 'threeEmails1@gmail.com,threeEmails2@gmail.com,threeEmails3@gmail.com'),
                        (98538, 'twoEmails1@gmail.com,twoEmails2@gmail.com'),
                        (98538, 'oneEmail1@gmail.com');

SELECT  pri,
        CASE
          WHEN sec = pri THEN NULL
          ELSE sec
        END AS sec,
        CASE
          WHEN ter = pri THEN NULL
          WHEN ter = sec THEN NULL
          ELSE ter
        END AS ter
  FROM  (
        SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 1) AS pri,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS sec,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS ter
          FROM  team 
          WHERE playerId = 98538
        ) a
```

Output:

```
pri                     sec                     ter
threeEmails1@gmail.com  threeEmails2@gmail.com  threeEmails3@gmail.com
twoEmails1@gmail.com    twoEmails2@gmail.com    (null)
oneEmail1@gmail.com     (null)                  (null)
```

To see it in action, have a look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e333b88/1).

**Note:** This will work for anything up to three email addresses.  In your example you seem to indicate that it sufficient for your problem, but if you have more than three emails in a single string then you will need to adapt the solution.  If you have *n* (an undefined number) of emails then this solution may not be suitable.